Explicit $2$-cocycle for $2^{1+2n}_+$
Let $p$ be a prime and $n\geq 1$, it is known that there are exactly two extraspecial groups of order $p^{1+2n}$, denoted by $p^{1+2n}_+$ and $p^{1+2n}_-$. They fit into central extensions
$$0\to(\mathbb{Z}/p)\to E\to(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{2n}\to 0.$$
When $p$ is odd, $E=p^{1+2n}_+$ has exponent $p$ and an explicit $2$-cocycle $\beta:V\times V\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ for $E$ (where $V=(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{2n}$, seen as an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space) is given by
$\beta(v,w)=\frac{1}{2}[v,w]$, with
$$[v,w]:=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n{v_iw_{n+i}-w_iv_{n+i}}.$$
Is there any explicit description for $\beta$ when $p=2$?

For $p = 2$, the explicit description of the cocycle $\beta$ is:
$$
\beta(v, w) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i w_{n+i} + v_{n+i} w_i,
$$
where $v$ and $w$ are elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^{2n}$.

@zeraouliarafik I do not think it is that easy.

@zeraouliarafik where did you get that formula from? Looks to me like a copy of the formula in the original post but using that +1=-1 in characteristic 2.

When $p=2$, the bilinear form given by commutators no longer specifies the extraspecial group. You need to use a quadratic form $q\colon V \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ giving the square map. A commutator in a group is always a product of three squares (via $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = (x^{-1})^2(xy^{-1})^2y^2$ ) and so $q$ determines the commutator map via $[x,y]=q(x+y)+q(x)+q(y)$.
Given the quadratic form $q$ determining the extraspecial group, there are many cocycles representing the cohomology class. They satisfy $\beta(x,x)=q(x)$, and $\beta(x,y)+\beta(y,x)=q(x+y)+q(x)+q(y)$. To choose such a $\beta$, choose a basis of $V$, say $v_1,\dots,v_{2n}$. Then set $\beta(v_i,v_i)=q(v_i)$, choose $\beta(v_i,v_j)$ arbitrarily for $i<j$, and then set $\beta(v_j,v_i)=q(v_i+v_j)+q(v_i)+q(v_j)+\beta(v_i,v_j)$. Now extend bilinearly.
There are two types of nonsingular quadratic forms, distinguished by their Arf invariants, and the recipe above works fine for both cases.

It might have made it clearer what was going on if I had written some of the plusses as minuses. But then people would complain that it makes no difference, so why do it? You can't win, you know.

Thanks a lot! I know where the condition $\beta(x,x)=q(x)$ comes from, but the other condition is not evident to me, does it follow from the cocycle equation?

I guess the point is that if you lift elements of $V$ to $E$ then $\beta(x,y)$ tells you how the lift of the product differs from the product of the lifts. So $\beta(x,y)-\beta(y,x)$ tells you the commutator of the lifts because $V$ is commutative. The formula for the commutator in terms of the square tells you this is $q(x-y)-q(x)+q(y)$. And as mentioned before, minus is plus. I hope that helps.

now it is clear, thank you again!

Btw, regarding $E=p^{1+2n}_{-}$, I was thinking that $\beta(v,w)=\frac{1}{2}([v,w]+q(v)+q(w))$ is the natural choice, but it fails to be a cocycle. Do you suggest another candidate?

For $p$ odd, you don't have a quadratic form. You have a symplectic form giving the commutators, and independently a linear form giving the $p$th powers. There's no connection between them. So just treat the two cocycles separately and add.

Yes, there are $B: V\times V\to \mathbb{F}_p$ and $q: V\to \mathbb{F}p$, and q is non trivial for $E=p^{1+2n}{-}$ (p odd). In what sense can I add them?

Cocycles form an abelian group. Just add them.

For the linear part, you can use the "carry digit" cocycle familiar from your youth.

Now I see your point, thank you!

The extraspecial group $P = 2_{+}^{1+2n}$ has generators $z$, $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$, $w_1$, $\ldots$, $w_n$, with $Z(P) = \langle z \rangle$ cyclic of order $2$ and
\begin{align*}
v_i^2 = w_i^2 = 1 & & \text{ for all } i\\
[v_i,v_j] = [w_i,w_j] = 1 && \text{ for all } i,j \\
[v_i,w_j] = 1 && \text{ for } i \neq j \\
[v_i,w_i] = z && \text{ for all } i \\
\end{align*}
So for $V = P/Z(P)$ you get the $2$-cocycle $f: V \times V \rightarrow Z(P)$ defined by $$f(v,v') = z^{\sum_{k = 1}^n i_k' j_k}$$
for $v = \prod_k v_k^{i_k} \prod_k w_k^{j_k}$ and $v' = \prod_k v_k^{i_k'} \prod_k w_k^{j_k'}$.
You can of course interpret this in terms of quadratic forms as in Dave Benson's answer. In this case $q: V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ with $q(v_i) = q(w_j) = 0$, with polarization $\beta$ defined by $\beta(v_i,v_j) = \beta(w_i,w_j) = 0$ and $\beta(v_i,w_j) = \delta_{i,j}$.
With some abuse of notation, the quadratic form on $V$ is defined by the formula $x^2 = z^{q(x)}$ for all $x \in P$.

thank you, I guess you mean $f(v,v')=z^{\sum_{k=1}^n{i_k j'_k}}$, right?

With what I wrote $vv' = f(v,v') \prod_k v_k^{i_k+i_k'} \prod_k w_k^{j_k+j_k'}$ in $P$, isn't that correct?

Well, the thing is that your formula for $f(v,v')$ implies that $f(v_i,w_j)=0$ for all $i,j$.

@Antoine I think he must mean $f(w_i,v_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

@DaveBenson I agree!
